# Using true UTF-8 in binary streams in java

Tags: java, utf-8

In Java, the `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` classes have `readUTF` and `writeUTF` which use a modified UTF-8 format. That is fine, if those files are only used by other Java programs, or the same Java program, but what if they are also read/written by a program in a different language? Or what if you are using a standard format, such as [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) which expects normal UTF-8 encoding?  Is there any way to use true UTF-8 encoding with `DataInput` and `DataOutput` besides manually encoding/decoding the strings with a Charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use InputStreamReader and InputStreamWriter instead, you can initialize a stream with a particular encoding.

If you are using json streams, use a library like gson which handles json streams too, which are supposed to adhere to json.org formatting, you should not use a string stream with a weird encoding for transporing json streams

Comment: Sorry, JSON is a bad example since it is text-based. And InputStreamWriter/Reader aren't really what I had in mind, because they only really work if you are dealing with purely text files. But what if you have a file which contains binary records, in which some of the fields are say integers and doubles, and other fields are UTF-8 encoded strings. How would you go about dealing with the strings in that case? The only way I can think of is to read them as `byte[]`s and then decode them.

Comment: If you are building this from the scratch and you can control the format of things, do never implement your own format. Use a serializer instead, like protocol buffers, xml,json/bson (etc) serializers.

Comment: If you can't help it then I would suggest to just read the bytes and offset the parts that are supposed to be unicode and translate them with new String(bytes, encoding).

Comment: I am learning Java now, and came across the readUTF and writeUTF methods and wondered why they used a modified UTF-8, and if there were similar methods for true UTF-8. Apparently not, although as @David Hofmann said it isn't hard to get around, and in fact it wouldn't be hard to subclass DataInputStream with a method that read true UTF-8 (although you would need to know how the string was terminated).